# How to extract high quality image still from an h264 video with FFmpeg compensating for compression?

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to extract an image still from an .mp4 video. However, when I do so - I still get pixellation/"blocks" in the image. This is the command I am using to extract an image starting @ 1 second with jpg quality the highest:

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:00:01 -i input.mp4 -frames:v 1 -q:v 1 -qmin 1  output.jpg
```

However, when I do that - I still get blocky pixellation. Reading, it is my understanding somehow mp4 - when using compression relies on frames 'around' it to 'fill in details'.

Here is a sample of what I am talking about: I want to get something like the 'first' image (as opposed to the 2nd, which uses ffmpeg) from the same video file:
[image]

How can I use ffmpeg so it properly extracts a "non-pixellated" image and gets the 'proper' decompressed image?

[image]

Comment: They both seem very blocky to me with the only difference being the one on the left is slightly lighter in color in that area to the one on the right.

Comment: (a) both images are magnified about 10x.
(b) basically the one on the left has smooth gradients - whereas the one on the right is blocky/chunky. do you know how to extract it properly with ffmpeg? thanks!

Comment: “do you know how to extract it properly with ffmpeg? thanks!” No I don’t. Please wait for someone with deeper FFmpeg experience to come by and assist.

Comment: Try PNG output format instead of JPEG.

Comment: did try that, doesn't make a different other than the file size is about 10x as large... any other ideas? thanks!

Comment: The right image definitely shows some compression artifacts but I am also not sure it's exactly the same region you're comparing? What happens when you output to PNG? How did you extract the single frame on the left? Is it a screenshot?

Comment: extracting a single frame from a video. and yes, it is the same region.